# Shooter hits his mark with probability. What's the average number of shots untill the first hit on the mark? What's the standard deviation?

Tags: probability

Shooter hits his mark with probability $p=\frac{1}{10}$.

**a)** What's the average number of shots untill the first hit on the mark?

**b)** What's the standard deviation?

**c)** What's the name of distribution used?

**My answers:**

**c)** Geometric Distribution

**a)**

$p=\frac{1}{10}$

$q=\frac{9}{10}$

$E(X)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}}=10$

10 shoots on average before first success

**b)**

Standard deviation = $\sqrt{\frac{\frac{9}{10}}{\frac{1}{100}}}=\sqrt{90}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$